# How to get SMTP details automatically in VB.NET like in thunderbird

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

I have made a VB.NET application. I have read I tutorials that how to use SMTP to send emails from VB.NET, and finally I got one working.

But I have an issue with it, I don't want to bother the user to input all his details like, SMTP server name and all those stuffs.

I just want that a user input their `Usename` and `Password` and all other necessary details gets available for the application. Same like thunderbird, as when I enter my `Usename` and `Password` in Mozilla thunderbird it automatically get all the other required data and configures my email account.

Now what I want to accomplish is that, a user should fill in their details i.e. `Usename` and `Password` & the email using their `Usename` and `Password` should be sent to the email specified in the program.

To explain more about the kind of my project is, when an error occurs I want the user to take a screenshot of it and email me it using this method. So that I can look into the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way of doing this. Each email setup is different and there is no automated configuration specification.

Thunderbird has a built in database that it's developers built and maintain to offer this functionality. See: https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/isp-database

You could do the same using the @domain.tld to enable you to match the users email provider with your database.

Microsoft Exchange does offer an automatic configuration endpoint, but I don't think it would prove useful to you as it isn't guaranteed to include SMTP information.