# How get the IMAP server related to an email address

Tags: python, email, server, imap, hostname

I would like to know if there exists a tool to get the IMAP server related to an email address.

For example, if I receive stack@hotmail.com, it should return: **imap-mail.outlook.com**. If I receive stack@outlook.com, it should also return: **imap-mail.outlook.com**

If no tool exists, I will create a little database with these informations.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no way to figure out programmatically which IMAP server(s) are available to the users of a domain, and traditionally, many organizations only have IMAP servers which are only available inside the intranet (though exceedingly public IMAPS servers and/or outsourced email solutions like Gmail are used many places). The mapping might not be 1:1; for example, an organization could direct users with last names which start on A-G to be on one server, H-N on another, etc.

Comment: In general there is no requirement that a mail address is "related" to an IMAP server, as there are other ways of accessing mailboxes (POP3, webmail only, forward to a different address/server/mailbox, ...). Thunderbird for example uses an [ISP database](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/isp-database) for known providers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get SMTP details automatically in VB.NET like in thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097359/how-to-get-smtp-details-automatically-in-vb-net-like-in-thunderbird)

Answer (score 1):

here is a way to detect it, using a free api, u can pass your email as a parameter and it will return the imap server

```
  def imapdetect(email):
    with request.urlopen('https://emailsettings.firetrust.com/settings?q=' + email) as response:
        if response.getcode() == 200:
            source = response.read()
            data = json.loads(source)
    for i in range(0, len(data["settings"]) + 1):
      if data["settings"][i]["protocol"] == "IMAP":
        imapserver = data["settings"][i]["address"]
        break 
    return imapserver
```